# Default properties (Colors) in Swing JButton (default)

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I tried to get the background color in Swing JButton (default). The color returned was RGB (238,238,238), but it's not exactly what I need.
How can I return the background color to default after I changed the background color to another color ?

```
JPanel panelButtons = new JPanel();
JButton button_01 = new JButton("01");
panelButtons.add(button_01);
```

***Default JButton:***

[image]

In a certain condition of my code, I defined:

```
button_01.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
button_01.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
```

***JButton with background color and foreground changed:***

[image]

In another condition of my code, I need to return the background color of JButton **button_01** to old configuration:

I tried to set background to **null** and to **UIManager.getColor("panelButtons.background")**:

```
button_01.setBackground(null);
button_01.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
```

**Or**

```
button_01.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("panelButtons.background"));
button_01.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
```

The result is the same:

[image]

How can I return the JButton **button_01** to default theme color ?

Comment: You state, `"I tried to set background to null, but is not worked:"` -- please test my code and let me know if it doesn't work. If it does work, then please create a similar small program that shows how **your** code doesn't work. ..... or perhaps I'm misunderstanding your requirements... are you simply trying to get the button's appearance back to the way it was initially?

Comment: Yet. I need to return the background color of the button to initial background color.

Comment: @LuxxMiner see the third image ... Not work my friend ... the color is different. when I created the button, I´m not defined the color of button (the color assumed is the default color of swing, like the first image) and after change the background color I need to return to default background and this options unfortunately not working for me.

Comment: Why dont you save the background color before changing it? Color defaultBtnColor = btn.getBackground();

Comment: Again, your creating and posting a simple [mcve] would likely clarify the issue for us. Of course no one can or should force you to do this, but in my experience, the effort is well worth it and often reduces a great deal of frustration on your part and on our part. Again, good luck.

Comment: @Stefan because the color returned is RGB (238, 238, 238) and this is not a real color or theme of JButton.

Comment: thanks bro. button_01.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("panelButtons.background"));   was all I needed

Answer (score 1):

> How can I return the background color to default after I changed the background color to another color ?

Try setting the JButton's background to `null`. For example:

```
myButton.setBackground(null);
```

---

For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ChangeButtonColor {

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      final JButton myButton = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Press Me To Swap Colors") {
         private boolean flag = true;

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Color c = flag ? Color.RED : null;
            ((AbstractButton) e.getSource()).setBackground(c);
            flag = !flag;
         }
      });

      JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
      mainPanel.add(myButton);

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: In my application I need to change the background color of jbutton after the application created the jbutton. This application communicate with a device and I need to change the background color in accordance with the return of the device, but if the condition again be the initial, is necessary to return the background color of the button to default.

Comment: @RafaelGuerra: setting the JButton's background Color to `null` should work. Again, were you able to test the code above in my answer to see if it works on your system? If it's not working in your program, then there may be a bug in the program that needs to be identified and corrected, and for our help, you'll need to give us more information, including a [mcve].

Comment: Hovercraft Full Of Eels ... If I initialize the JButton with setting the background color (null) your answer is correct, but in my application I´m not define the background color (the JButton assumes the default color in Swing), this is the problem, I need to return to default theme, understand me ?

Comment: @RafaelGuerra: no, I'm sorry, but I'm not clear on the problem. Please consider editing your question, providing the important details, and again, consider posting a [mcve], since that is usually the best way to get all of us to fully understand your problem. Much luck.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong UIManager property. You need to use "Button.background". That is the universal way to get the background across all Java Look And Feels.

```
button.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
```